How can use my webcomponents stencil in my proyect React-TSX
I have my component library installed and I define the defineCustomElements , and so I can use all my components if I use react JS but, if I use react TSX when using the component it gives me the following Property 'my-component' does not exist on type 'JSX. IntrinsicElements'.ts
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
// Iportamos los estilos generales
 import '@mycomponents/dist/components-ui.css'
// Importamos los componentes
import { defineCustomElements } from "@mycomponents/dist/loader"
// ...
// Registramos los componentes
defineCustomElements(window)

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

I have seen that if I declare a global.d.ts inside src with this
declare namespace JSX {
    interface IntrinsicElements {
        "my-component": any,
    }
}

It stops giving me the error now. But there is no way to avoid doing this? I have tried the following to reference the components.d.ts that is generated from stencil but it does not work
/// <reference path='./node_modules/@mycomponents/dist/types/components.d.ts' />

